# Effecient way to find if a key from a list of maps exists within another list of maps

Tags: arrays, list, go, maps

I have two lists of maps. We'll call them A, which exists within a database, and B, which is live results from a sensor.

A shares Key/Values From B

Example looks like:

```
A = [
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.547354",
        "id": 1,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.1",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 2,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.2",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
        "id": 3,
        "ip_address": "192.168.1.3",
        "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    }
]

B = [
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.1',
        'status': True
    },
    {
        'mac_address': 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
        'ip_address': '192.168.1.2',
        'status': True
    }
]
```

What's the best way way to find out any missing maps from B compared to A by the Value `ip_address`.

For example, we can tell by looking at the above that the map which contains the ip_address "192.168.1.3" doesn't exist within B. The aim is to try and find a list of values which don't exist between the two, if any.

The expected output is a list like: `["192.168.1.3"]`

Answer (score 1):

I come up with semi efficient solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "created_at":  "2020-09-19T17:25:29.547354",
            "id":          1,
            "ip_address":  "192.168.1.1",
            "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
        },
        {
            "created_at":  "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
            "id":          2,
            "ip_address":  "192.168.1.2",
            "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
        },
        {
            "created_at":  "2020-09-19T17:25:29.564472",
            "id":          3,
            "ip_address":  "192.168.1.3",
            "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
        },
    }

    b := []map[string]interface{}{
        {
            "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "ip_address":  "192.168.1.1",
            "status":      true,
        },
        {
            "mac_address": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "ip_address":  "192.168.1.2",
            "status":      true,
        },
    }

    c, d := collectIpAddresses(a), collectIpAddresses(b)

    var missing []string

    for k := range c {
        if !d[k] {
            missing = append(missing, k)
        }
    }

    for k := range d {
        if !c[k] {
            missing = append(missing, k)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(missing)
}

// stores data in more efficient data-structure for searching
func collectIpAddresses(a []map[string]interface{}) map[string]bool {
    b := make(map[string]bool, len(a))
    for _, v := range a {
        b[v["ip_address"].(string)] = true
    }
    return b
}
```

This is a good solution because it provides `O(m+n)` complexity (where `m` is `len(a)` and `n` is `len(b)`).

In contrary, [that](https://play.golang.org/p/Qbh_iXDxQ8B) solution which uses a `loop within a loop` will have a complexity of `O(m*n)`. That complexity will dramatically reduce the performance of the algorithm on larger datasets.

Although, because allocating is extremely slow, on a dataset as provided by OP, the last solution will provide better results. This might be a catch depending the size of the dataset to iterate.

Comment: why do you need to allocate twice more maps than the initial set of provided data ? Besides, you could delete from d when you iterate over c. Reason is to reduce the iteratons length over d. In a more general way, you can not talk about performance or efficiency unless you have setup a test suite, to ensure correctness, and more importantly, a reliable benchmark setup. Unless that, this is all very theorical and hypothetical. Finally, OP does not specify the size of the dataspace, so, we really cant decide which implementation is the best,even if they are perfect, zero alloc etc.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about memory in this case as only thing that gets allocated is map with very small elements (9 bites per element). The strings are not getting copied and after little fix (allocating map with initial size) I don't think two relatively small allocations can hurt performance that much. My goal was to get smallest time complexity which is mostly linear except some hash collisions. Nevertheless, if you can manage to write solution that has linear time and does not allocate any memory, am excited to see it.

Comment: in linear time and no allocation, just reuse memory from a along its iteration to stack unfound items in b.

Comment: the thing is on such small dataset, you better have to consume the cpu rather than the memory. https://play.golang.org/p/WwiGMVFPfZG let me know what you think. More generally, i d like to emphase the fact that without a clear idea of the size of the dataset, we cannot give a proper solution with certainty.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/HHRPbObnrrz, well if I change the order of arguments, return values are different. I may also be wrong but you are using two loops nested in each other which makes for O(n * n) complexity. But I agree that with so small dataset, your solution, with no bugs, is faster because of that exponential curve.

Comment: I took liberty to summarize all that and add to your answer, feel free to remove or adjust. Although, given OP description, `What's the best way way to find out any missing maps from B compared to A by the Value ip_address.` I think your solution could be improved to `O(m)`.